# What is the fastest and safest way to send large number of requests with HttpClient?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Initially I used the following to send out large number of URLs:

```
for (...) {
  using (var client = new HttpClient()) {
    client.GetAsync(url);
  } 
}
```

Turns out, that is the [wrong way](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) to use HttpClient, because .Dispose leaves the connection in place on the other side thereby wasting server resources. The suggested fix to this is to use a shared copy of httpClient:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
for (...) {
  client.GetAsync(url);
}
```

This approach suffers from an even worse problem.  If your target url is behind a load balancer, httpClient establishes a connection with the first box it's routed to and every subsequent hit will go to that box ignoring the rest of the web farm.

So what is the correct way to use HttpClient in a way that doesn't waste resources on the other end of the connection and is able to utilize the entire web farm?

Comment: Maybe initialize a couple of `HttpClient` objects and have them work on their own 'chunks' of the load in parallel. Otherwise you're essentially doing exactly what [`keep-alive`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) was invented to prevent.

Comment: Investigate [`HttpClientFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.2); it uses a pool of HttpClients and reuses the connection only if the DNS resolves to the same IP. Josef Ottosson has a [good introduction](https://josefottosson.se/you-are-probably-still-using-httpclient-wrong-and-it-is-destabilizing-your-software/).

Comment: @DourHighArch Not sure that's going to work out, because all the URLs are a variation of http://www.foo.com/productid={xxxxx}, so it will resolve it to the same IP.

Comment: If the website is using round-robin DNS for its load balancing then Dour's solution would be correct if true. If the website is using a reverse proxy as its load balancer then it doesn't matter, the requests will be delegated by the server not the client.

Comment: @AlphaDelta But that's not what is happening.  It seems like the connection is never broken, simply reused and that connection is to a specific server, rather than the load balancer.

Comment: It seems like the connection is never broken because it isn't broken, at least until the connection times out, by way of keep-alive. You can set the HTTP header `Connection` to `close` if you like ([see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Connection#Directives)), but it is not ideal at all because the overhead of creating a new connection for each request would most likely be worse than bypassing any loadbalancer. Doing all the work with one HttpClient (as in your question), using multiple HttpClients in parallel, or using Dour's solution should all be valid enough.

Comment: There's no real fastest or safest way, because it entirely depends on the target. If the server is using round-robin DNS or something similar where the client is the primary factor in the load balancing, use Dour's solution. If it is the server who is the primary factor in the load balancing, using the same HttpClient for all requests is the safest, using multiple in parallel is the fastest.

Comment: Does client sends subsequent requests to the same box even when you uses `RequestMessage`? `var request = new HttpRequestMessage { Method = HttpMethod.Get, RequestUri = url }` and then `client.Send(request)`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want use multiple HTTP connections, a straightforward solution would be something like this:

```cs
const int size = 12;
var clients = new HttpClient[size];
for (var i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    clients[i] = new HttpClient();
}

int j = 0;
for (...)
{
    clients[j++%size].GetAsync(url); // todo: handle async correctly
}
```

If you are inside ASP.NET Core application, I would urge you to consider using [IHttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.0).

If you are not using IHttpClientFactory be aware that if DNS change occurs during the lifetime of your application, it won't be reflected.